# Macvim spell check not working with some latex files

Tags: vim, spelling

I am using MacVim with Tex-suite. The spell checking works on main.tex, but doesn't work on other .tex files. Both the main.tex and other .tex files have filetype set to tex. Changing the filetype to plaintex makes spell check work, but it removes the latex syntax highlighting. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Some more information is needed, I'm afraid.

Comment: Question is rather old but I think it's answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658588/vim-spell-checking-filetype-tex-files